# websphere multiple classloaders fixes class not found exception

Tags: websphere, classloader, classnotfound

Hi we use websphere in my company

The websphere installation has two ears ear1 and ear2

We have a policy of a singleclassloader

When set to singleclassloader we get a class not found exception from ear2
spring-oxm3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm.MarshallingFailureException class not found

But by enabling "multiple classloaders" the problem goes away.

1. Why would the company have a policy of enforcing "single classloader" ?
2. Is the classnotfound exception caused because a class is defined a jar in both
    ear1 and ear2?
    eg ear1:jar1 and ear2:spring-oxm3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
    And X is loaded from ear1:jar1 and thereby is spring-oxm3.1.0.RELEASE.jar is not loaded ? And when the request runs it fails and complains that MarshallingFailureException is not found?

Would that explain why the class is not found?

So is the solution to find what is the jar in ear1 that is causing spring-oxm3.1.0.Release.jar not to load? And remove it?
Could it be xerces or jaxb?
(We're running java version 1.5)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- In that old version of Java, all XML-related jars had many problems.
- Your error details will tell you why the class is not being loaded. Most likely, it is a class with the same package/name but in a different jar
- Company policies have to do with all the factors involved - development, maintenance, dependency management, and so on.